# how to backup mysql database in store procedure or event?

Tags: mysql, database, backup

Is there a way to backup database using event scheduler in mysql?
i want to run this event in phpmyadmin, 
now i have a code for backing up a single table, but i want it to be a single file of database.. is that posible?

Comment: what kind of backup? there are multiple types of backups and they could be different depending of engine of the tables, can you be more specific?

Comment: i just want a dump file (sql file) of my whole database, and i want to create that using procedure or event .